What type of rent would make more sense here?
From John Le Carré's Smiley's People:

“More coffee, George?”
“No, thank you, Peter. No, I don’t think so. No.”
“They seem to have soup of some sort. Unless that was the coffee.”
“Thank you, I think I’ve consumed about all I can manage,” said Smiley, in quite a general tone, as if anyone who wished to hear was welcome.
“Well, maybe I’ll just order something for rent,” said Guillam.
“Rent? I’m sorry. Of course. God knows what they must live on.”

What type of rent does Guillam mean? Does that mean Guillam is considering ordering something to pay for their place at the table, or to help the owner of the café to pay his rent?

The group needs to unobtrusively remain in their location for an indeterminate period of time. Sitting at a table for potentially hours without ordering anything will invite the ire of the proprietor and potentially arouse the suspicions of observers. Simply handing money to the owner and saying "let us sit here and leave us alone" would be suspicious and absolutely informs the owner that they have ulterior motives. So buying more food and drink, even though they've already established that they don't need any in general and don't want the subpar output of the "wretched Turkish kitchen" in particular, is a sensible way to exchange money for what they really want: time occupying this specific space, without undue attention. Thus, "rent".
The "God knows what they must live on" is simply another dig at the quality of the establishment, emphasizing that he can't imagine anyone paying money for the food and drink offered there.

But does "rent" refer to them renting the table from the restaurant, or contributing towards the rent that the restaurant pays their landlord? I think that's what the OP was asking (see the last paragraph of the question) and this answer, while correct, doesn't quite address that subtlety of meaning.

To me the context is clearly indicating that they are paying their own "rent" for their use of the space: "Here's several sentences about why I don't want to eat this food, so why would I order any? To 'rent' our table". Without authorial dicta I can't say this is unchallengeable, but it strikes me as a very odd non sequitur to suddenly switch to talking about a particular bill the restauranteur may or may not even face. "Here's several sentences about why I don't want to eat this food, so why would I order any? To pay the medical bills of the cook's family".

It's a small point, but I notice that Guillam says "for rent" rather than "for their rent". I think that points towards them paying their own "rent", as the answer says.
